# No se ejecuta script python con crontab

Tags: crontab

Quiero automatizar la ejecución de un programa que he hecho, para ello encontré la herramienta `crontab`. Para ello lo ejecuto como `sudo`

```
sudo contrab -e
```

Una vez aquí, le digo que quiero que mi script se ejecute cada día a las 13:30, para ello le defino dicha fecha y hora y la ruta de mi script.

```
13 30 * * * /home/pi/Project/main.py
```

Como este [documento](https://www.redeszone.net/2017/01/09/utilizar-cron-crontab-linux-programar-tareas/) especifica. Pero no va, no hace absolutamente nada, ¿alguien puede ayudarme?

Yo imagino es un problema de ruta, que hay algo que no le estoy diciendo, quizás sea alguno de los `imports` que hago, `os`,`time`,`ivport`, pero no logro encontrar el motivo del error.

**PRUEBAS**

```
13 30 * * * usr/bin/python/home/pi/Project/main.py
@reebot usr/bin/python/home/pi/Project/main.py #por si era un problema de hora
```

Comment: para ejecutar debes indicar qué lo ejecuta, ergo decir `13 30 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Project/main.py`, donde el `/usr/bin/` puede cambiar (lo consigues diciendo `which python`). También conviene revisar los permisos del fichero

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar pero eso también lo probé, me he olvidado ponerlo (tanto con Python como con Python3). Ahora lo añado

Comment: ojo, le falta la barra inicial al `usr/bin/....` y debes separarlo: `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.../main.py`. Para probar si el comando funciona, ejecútalo a mano antes. Por otra parte, ¿has mirado si crontab está funcionando? `ps aux | grep crontab`

Comment: El comando `python /usr/bin/python /home/pi/.../main.py` no me funciona pues dice `[errno 20] Not a directory`.

Comment: Puse ... para no poner toda la ruta

Comment: Te he puesto un post más extenso abajo pero creo que se limita a que primero tienes que definir los minutos y luego la hora.

Comment: ¿Y el script cuál es? Al menos para ver el encabezado y confirmar cosas que deberían estar

Comment: @fedorqui yo también jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solución fué,

```
@reebot python /home/pi/Project/main.py
```

no poner `usr/bin/python`. La respuesta de @andopr es la más cercana, pero la dejo aquí separado para que quede claro para futuras consultas.

Comment: es que no era `urb/bin/python` sino el resultado de `which python`, que te dará la ruta exacta

Answer (score 3):

*Edito:*  en el crontab primero van los minutos!!! entonces es

```
30 13 * * * python /ruta/script.py
```

---

¿Entiendo que el script es ejecutable?
para ello tendrías que haber ejecutado: `chmod u+x /home/pi/Project/main.py`

¿Y supongo que la primera línea de tu script es `#!/usr/bin/python` ?

A parte, la prueba 1 que has hecho está mal, porque no es `/usr/bin/python/home/...` en todo caso sería `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Project/main.py`, con espacio, porque lo que estás intentando es decirle a bash dónde está instalado Python. Es normal que te diga que no existe.

¿Has probado que el script se ejecuta correctamente desde la terminal, sin pasarlo por el cron?

Puedes probar, para que te vuelque todos los resultados de la ejecución del cron en un fichero temporal de salida:

`13 30 * * * python /home/pi/Project/main.py > /tmp/salida.log 2>&1`

¿Puedes mostrar tu script?

Comment: Lo del formato es cierto! https://crontab.guru nos muestra que no es correcto decir `13 30 ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a ejecutar solo el Script

```
/usr/bin/python  /___ruta_hasta_el_proyecto__/main.py
```

*Recuerda que CRON se ejecuta sin una ruta base especifica, por eso es bueno colocar las rutas absolutas desde la raíz* `/` *hasta el script a ejecutar*

y mira que resultado te da, si se ejecuta, es que el fichero Python, `main.py`, es correcto.
En caso contrario, el problema no estaría en el Cron, si no en tu programa.

.
Luego realiza una  prueba colocando la ejecución del Cron a cada minuto

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python  /___ruta_hasta_el_proyecto__/main.py > /dev/stdout
```

y verifica si cada minuto, se ejecuta

> comprueba si usas `python` o `python3`